# Python error not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this:

```
put(('%s%s.tar.gz' % config.SERVER_PROJECT_PATH, config.RELEASE))
```

**TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**

I just want insert two variables in to the string, **is my syntax correct?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the two values in a tuple:

```
put('%s%s.tar.gz' % (config.SERVER_PROJECT_PATH, config.RELEASE))
```

otherwise Python sees this as two separate expressions to form a tuple, `'%s%s.tar.gz' % config.SERVER_PROJECT_PATH` and `config.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is incorrect.  The string formatting arguments must be a tuple.  You are creating a tuple with the formatted string and the second formatting argument.  Use this instead:

```
put("%s%s.tar.gz" % (config.SERVER_PROJECT_PATH, config.RELEASE))
```